# Count streaks or consecutive repeat of values DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that is quite simple:

| User | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | May 2021 | Success |
| Doe | May 2021 | Fail |
| John | Aug 2021 | Fail |
| Doe | Aug 2021 | Fail |
| Doe | Sep 2021 | Success |
| Doe | Oct 2021 | Success |
| John | OCt 2021 | Fail |

I want to count how many times a user fails repeatedly but reset the count when it succeeds.

In the example above I would want to add a column like this :

| User | Date | Status | Streak |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | May 2021 | Success | 0 |
| Doe | May 2021 | Fail | 0 |
| John | Aug 2021 | Fail | 0 |
| Doe | Aug 2021 | Fail | 1 |
| Doe | Sep 2021 | Success | 0 |
| Doe | Oct 2021 | Success | 0 |
| John | OCt 2021 | Fail | 1 |

Now this streak count would have to increase even if the user did  not appear in a month as the example shown.   I can not use power query and my main concern is the discrepancy in dates since sometimes users can have a streak since they only got tested months apart. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
Table.AddColumn(
    #"Previous Step",
    "Streak",
    (r) => if r[Status] = "Fail"
           then List.Count(
                    List.LastN(
                        Table.SelectRows(
                            #"Previous Step",
                            each [User] = r[User] and [Date] < r[Date]
                        )[Status],
                        each _ = "Fail"
                    )
                )
           else 0,
    Int64.Type
)
```

If the `[Status]` is "Fail", then it will take the table from the `#"Previous Step"` and [`Table.SelectRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectrows) just the rows where the `[User]` is the same as in the current row and the `[Date]` is before the date in the current row and return just the `[Status]` column from that filtered table. Treating this single column as a list, it then takes the [`List.LastN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-lastn) occurrences of "Fail" from that list and does a `List.Count` of how many of those there are.

Answer (score 1):

can you add conditional column ?

if status = success new_column = 0 , like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The streak is dependent on previous rows so a simple conditional column isn't flexible enough.