# Power BI: Count Consecutive occurrences of a value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset that has the following structure: A Name, A Week Identifier, A Binary Conditional column.  Using PowerBI/DAX, I want to create a column called "Streak" that evaluates how many **consecutive** times the "DidItHappen" column = 1 for the Same "Name":

```
| Name       | Week  | DidItHappen |Streak|
| Person A   | 15    | 1           | 1    |
| Person A   | 16    | 1           | 2    |
| Person B   | 15    | 1           | 1    |
| Person B   | 16    | 0           | 0    |
| Person B   | 17    | 1           | 1    |
| Person C   | 15    | 0           | 0    |
| Person C   | 16    | 0           | 0    |
| Person C   | 17    | 1           | 1    |
| Person C   | 18    | 1           | 2    |
| Person C   | 19    | 0           | 0    |
| Person C   | 20    | 1           | 1    |
| Person C   | 21    | 1           | 2    |
| Person C   | 22    | 1           | 3    |
| Person C   | 23    | 1           | 4    |
| Person C   | 24    | 0           | 0    |
| Person C   | 25    | 1           | 1    |
```

If "DidItHappen"=0 then the Streak should be **always** 0 (regardless if it is consecutive or not).
The first instance that "DidItHappen"=1 for a "Name", the Streak should be 1.
All subsequent consecutive occurrences that "DidItHappen"=1 for the Same "Name" **and **Consecutive "Week" should increase the "Streak" by 1.

Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

I tried to Index the column and use adjust the code in the following post:

[Count streaks or consecutive repeat of values DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467906/count-streaks-or-consecutive-repeat-of-values-dax)

---

Thanks for your response, @Zach.  I was attempting to respond but it limits the comments.  Here is how I adapted your code:

```
Count Winning Streak =
VAR person =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( '22PPReport-VetList'[PersonnelNumber] )
VAR last_week =
    MAX ( '22PPReport-VetList'[PayPeriodID] )
VAR lastweekStart =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( '22PPReport-VetList'[PayPeriodID] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( '22PPReport-VetList' ),
            '22PPReport-VetList'[PersonnelNumber] = person
                && '22PPReport-VetList'[UsedMLLWOP] = 0
                && '22PPReport-VetList'[PayPeriodID] < last_week
        )
    )
VAR streak =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( '22PPReport-VetList' ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( '22PPReport-VetList' ),
            '22PPReport-VetList'[PersonnelNumber] = person
                && '22PPReport-VetList'[PayPeriodID] <= last_week
                && '22PPReport-VetList'[PayPeriodID] >= lastweekStart
                && '22PPReport-VetList'[UsedMLLWOP] = 1
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( '22PPReport-VetList'[UsedMLLWOP] ) = 0, 0, streak )
```

Here are the actual data elements with the name I previously referred to them as in parenthesis.

(Previously Referred to as)Data elements:
(Name) - PersonnelNumber - Int64.Type
(Week) - PayPeriodID - Int64.Type
(DidItHappen) - UsedMLLWOP - type number

[image: Here is an image of the actual table (Named: 22PPReport-VetList) with values blurred out for privacy reasons.]

Comment: are payperiodid's like weeks of the year?

Comment: Very similar, yes...payperiods are essentially two calendar weeks put together.  So they are sequential 4 digit integers.

Answer (score 1):

Give this measure a try

```
Count Winning Streak =
VAR person =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table'[ Name       ] )
VAR last_week =
    MAX ( 'table'[ Week  ] )
VAR lastweekStart =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'table'[ Week  ] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'table' ),
            'table'[ Name       ] = person
                && 'table'[ DidItHappen ] = 0
                && 'table'[ Week  ] < last_week
        )
    )
VAR streak =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'table' ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'table' ),
            'table'[ Name       ] = person
                && 'table'[ Week  ] <= last_week
                && 'table'[ Week  ] >= lastweekStart
                && 'table'[ DidItHappen ] = 1
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table'[ DidItHappen ] ) = 0, 0, streak )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, Zach!  I tried to adapt your measure to my table and I am not sure where I went wrong.  I had to change some parameters of the table for fear of privacy but to make sure I have adapted it properly, I am providing an image with the secure portion  blurred out.